# Click not possible after applying js function

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, onclick

I'm sorry this is going to be confusing, I have applied a js function to a div of a sidebar so when you click another bar slides from the left. But it used to work with the hover css function. The thing is on the sliding sidebar there are a few menus you can click. Now that I've changed the way the bar slides (with css), you can't click on them anymore.

My code is down there but the snippet isn't looking good at all because the dimensions are wrong I guess.. Sorry but you can see what it looks like [here](http://typhotoshop.tumblr.com/)

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navi").click(function(){
$("#navi .fa-chevron-down").toggleClass("rtoate180");
$("#navigation").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
</script>
```

```css
#more{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0px;
padding:5px;
font-size:20px;
line-height:40px;
text-align:center;
width:60px;
height:40px;
display:inline-block;
{block:IfSidebarRight}
right:0px;
left:auto;
{/block:IfSidebarRight}
}


.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    left:18px;
    top:25px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color:{color:Main icon background};
    margin: 6px 0px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}

/*------ SIDEBAR -----*/  
 
#sidebar{
width:300px;
height:100%;
margin-left:-300px;
{block:IfSidebarRight}
margin-left:300px;
{/block:IfSidebarRight}
top:0px;
}
 
.change ~ #sidebar2{
margin-left:365px;
{block:IfSidebarRight}
margin-left:-300px;
{/block:IfSidebarRight}
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s  ease;
-o-transition: all .5s  ease;
transition: all .5s  ease;
}
 
/*------ Narrow sidebar -----*/
 
#sidebar1{
    z-index:10;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0;
width:70px;
height:100%;
background:{color:Narrow sidebar background};
{block:IfSidebarRight}
right:0;
left:auto;
{/block:IfSidebarRight}
}

/*------ Wide sidebar -----*/
 
#sidebar2{
    z-index:0;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
margin-left:65px;
width:220px;
height:100%;
background:{color:Wide sidebar background};
background-image:url({image:Wide sidebar background});
{block:IfWideSidebarBackgroundTransparent}
background:transparent;
{/block:IfWideSidebarBackgroundTransparent}
{block:IfSidebarRight}
margin-left:75px;
{/block:IfSidebarRight}
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s  ease;
-o-transition: all .5s  ease;
transition: all .5s  ease;
}

/* Avatar */
 
#avatar {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 65px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border:0px solid
  z-index:10;
}

#avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#avatar img:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
}

/* Description */
 
#description{
    position:relative;
margin-left:20px;
color:{color:Description};
background:{color:Description background};
border:5px solid {color:Description background};
max-height:300px;
padding:10px;
width:150px;
overflow-y:auto;
margin-top:20px;
font-size:13px;
line-height:18px;
}
 
#description:after{ 
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0;
border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -15px;
top: 57px;
}
 
/* Search box */
 
#search{
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:20px;
width:180px;
height:30px;
overflow:hidden;
color:{color:Search};
background:{color:Search box background};
}
 
#search i{
position:absolute;
margin-left:67px;
margin-top:9px;
color:{color:Search}!important;
font-size:12px;
z-index:1000;
}
 
/* Navigation */
 
#navi{
    cursor:pointer;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:20px;
width:170px;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
padding-left:10px;
overflow:hidden;
color:{color:Navigation};
background:{color:Navigation background};
font-size:12px;
text-align:left;
}
 
#navi i{
position:absolute;
margin-left:77px;
margin-top:10px;
color:{color:Navigation}!important;
font-size:12px;
}

#navi .fa-chevron-down {
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
.rtoate180 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
 
#navigation{
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:20px;
width:180px;
overflow:hidden;
display:none;
font-size:12px;
background:{color:Navigation background};
}

 
#navigationin a{
display:block;
font-size:12px;
line-height:18px;
width:180px;
overflow:hidden;
color:{color:Navigation link};
border-bottom:1px solid {color:Wide sidebar background};
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
-webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .7s  ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .7s  ease-in-out;
transition: all .7s  ease-in-out;
}
 
#navigationin a:hover{
cursor:pointer;
box-shadow: inset 180px 0 0 0 {color:Wide sidebar background};
color:{color:Hover};
-webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .7s  ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .7s  ease-in-out;
transition: all .7s  ease-in-out;
}
 
/* Social icons */
 
#socialicons{
margin-top:0px;
}
 
#socialicons i{
display:inline-block;  
color:{color:Navigation link}!important;
margin:5px;
font-size:15px;
}
 
#socialicons i:hover{
color:{color:Hover}!important;
}
 
/*----- MAIN CONTAINER -----*/
 
#container{
position:absolute;
top: 50px;
left:50%;
margin-bottom:10px;
min-height:500px;
width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
width: -o-calc(100% - 100px);
width: calc(100% - 100px);
min-width:610px;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
z-index:1;
{block:IfShowHeader}
top: -moz-calc(100% + 50px);
top: -webkit-calc(100% + 50px);
top: -o-calc(100% + 50px);
top: calc(100% + 50px);
{/block:IfShowHeader}
{block:TagPage}
top:50px;
{/block:TagPage}
{block:SearchPage}
top:50px;
{/block:SearchPage}  
{block:PermalinkPage}
top:50px;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
 
}
```

```html
<div id="more">

<div id="sidebar">

<div id="sidebar1" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>

<div id="avatar"><img src="{image:Avatar}"></div>

</div>
 
<div id="sidebar2">
 

<div id="description">
{Description}</div>

<div id="search">
<form action="/search" method="get"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
<input type="text" name="q" value="SEARCH" style="position:absolute; left:20px; width:160px; height:25px; padding-left:10px; font-family:{select:Body font}; font-size: 12px; background:transparent; border:1px solid transparent; color:{color:Search};"/></form>
</div>

<div id="navi"> NAVIGATION <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
 
<!--Navigation-->
<div id="navigation">
 
<div id="navigationin">

<a href="{text:Link One Url}">{text:Link One Title}</a>

<a href="{text:Link Two Url}">{text:Link Two Title}</a>

<a href="{text:Link Three Url}">{text:Link Three Title}</a>

<a href="{text:Link Four Url}">{text:Link Four Title}</a>

<a href="{text:Link Five Url}">{text:Link Five Title}</a>

</div>
<!--End navigationin-->
 
<div id="socialicons">
<center>
<a href="{text:Facebook url}"  target = "_blank" title="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
  <a href="{text:Twitter url}" target="_blank" title="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
  <a href="{text:Flickr url}" title="flickr"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a>
<a href="{text:Youtube url}" target="_blank" title="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</center>
</div>
<!--End socialicons-->
 
</div>

 
</div>
<!--End sidebar1-->
 
</div>
<!--End sidebar-->
 
</div>
<!--End more-->
```

Thank you so much if you can help me I know it's not clear.. I'm sorry!

Comment: You'll need to create a minimum viable example in a jsFiddle or something. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There's no need to be sorry. Many questions start with "I am sorry". Don't be... just ask your question. We are here for to answer and help after all :)

Comment: That's true but some people are less understanding than you are.. ^^ @TonyTannous

Comment: On [tag:CSS] or [tag:HTML] I wouldn't consider my self "more understanding". I only help here by editing posts to improve readability since it increases the chances OP gets an answer.
I would answer if it is Operating System related thing :) which I absolutely loves. But each one and the things he like.

Answer (score 2):

Use the developer tools and check out `#container` - it's covering your sidebar, so - you can't click what's under it.

Comment: Oh that's right, thank you! So I think I'm just going to set a higher z-index for the sidebar. It will work right?

Comment: Or, a lower z-index on the other - depending. Remember, you have to have 'position' set on an element - `relative`, `fixed` etc - or z-index will not take effect. : )

Comment: I'm very sorry, you were already very nice to help but I tried doing that and it didn't work :/ EDIT: Nevermind : setting a higher z-index didn't work but setting lower the other did! Thank you 1000 times! You're the best

Comment: You can always rethink the layout in general. I'd avoid id's if you can. : )

Comment: Why do you think so? Well I trust you maybe if I have time one day I will do that!